# Delphi OpenOffice open .doc save as .odt

Tags: delphi

I'm using Delphi to open a MS Word .doc document and save it as a text file.  What I need to do now is to save it as a .odt file.

I can't find the filter properties I should use.

This is the code snippet for the save-to-text-file functionality:

```
  wProperties := VarArrayCreate([0, 0], varVariant);
  wProperties[0] := MakePropertyValue('FilterName', 'Text');

  fDocument.StoreAsURL('file:///'+ StringReplace(FileName, '\', '/', [rfIgnoreCase,     rfReplaceAll]), wProperties);
```

Filename would have something like "c:\temp\aaa.txt" .

What filter name value should I use to store as an odt file?

Note: I'm actually using LibreOffice if that makes any difference.

Comment: Here is a [`list of available filters`](https://wiki.openoffice.org/wiki/Framework/Article/Filter/FilterList_OOo_3_0).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The filter name that you need to use is `'writer8'`.

Comment: @David -  That helped a great deal.. +10 for the answer. Solved an issue for which I was breaking my head. Considering the poor online support we have for open office related issue, I would give you a +100. Kudos..

Answer (score 0):

There's a Wiki filterlist as API Names online:
[Filterlist as API Name for Property Values](https://wiki.openoffice.org/wiki/Framework/Article/Filter/FilterList_OOo_3_0)